# reftex select buffer

Tags: pdf-tools, reftex-mode

I use auctex/reftex with pdftools for preview. I use a vertical split C-x 3 of the emacs frame with the left buffer being the pdf preview and the right buffer being the latex file.
When I invoke reftex select buffer with keystrokes C-c )  the reftex buffer and latex buffer take the entire frame hiding the pdf preview. Is it possible to customize the reftex select buffer so that: (i)  it appears only in the right half of the frame below my latex file and (ii) the reftex and latex buffers do not hide the pdf preview.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, this is not possible by default. However, you could easily modify the code to achieve it. For that, change the line:

```
(switch-to-buffer-other-window "*RefTeX Select*")
```

in the function `reftex-select-with-char` to:

```
(select-window (display-buffer-below-selected (get-buffer-create "*RefTeX Select*") nil))
```

and similar for the subsequent created windows (the code contains useful comments for 'discovering' lines/functions that create new windows).

You might also submit a feature request to make it customizable (e.g. by using the function `display-buffer-in-direction`) to the [bug-gnu-emacs mailing list](https://mail.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-gnu-emacs).